# How to prevent delete query in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have created a database through Entity Framework Code First Approach and My application is ready and running live . The problem is that I did not turned "False" on Cascade Delete at the time of creating database.
Now if I delete any record from one table that is referenced with another table through foreign so all the record containing foreign key of deleted row is deleted from another table .
Practically demonstration :

Let say I have a Table called Passenger:

```
ID     Name    CategoryID
1      ABC         1
```

CategoryID here is a foreign key

Here is the category Table

```
ID    Name   
1     Gold
```

Let say I run my query on category table

```
delete from Category where ID = 1
```

Now all the record from my Passenger Table is deleted . I want to restrict it. Is it Possible through SQL now ?

Comment: Yes, you can prevent deleting, by changing your logic. If some category is no longer used, you can deactivate it. Add boolean field into `Category` table, let say `Active`, then use `Update` statement. For example: `UPDATE Category Set Active = 'false'`

Comment: @MaciejLos In my real application I have implemented that logic I have a bool property and through application interface if someone is going to delete any particular record , that property is going to be "true". I am asking what if someone run query on sql by mistak .. than it will delete the record and all the referenced record too.. This is what i want to restrict

Comment: You should disallow that person to admin your database :)

Comment: Please beware that EF also acts on cascaded delete specifications. If it's true in the mapping it will assume that the database takes care of it and it won't emit delete statements for child records. So if you're going to change the database you must be really sure that there are no cases in you code where child records are *supposed* to be deleted with their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose 
[This is what you are looking for](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3b59bcbd-fa02-4c57-8775-acf8f0532501/trigger-to-prevent-record-deletion?forum=transactsql) :

```
alter TRIGGER customers_del_prevent
ON dbo.customers 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
 insert into dbo.log
    values ('DELETE')   
 RAISERROR ('Deletions not allowed from this table (source = instead of)', 16, 1)   
 END
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: @Faizan Eh... This blocks *all* deletes. You won't be able to delete any `Passenger` *ever*, even when you try to do that directly. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Actually I had implemented soft delete functionality through interface by adding bool value. and I am getting list of only those passengers whose bool property is false.

Comment: so if someone want to delete any Passenger they can just delete that and behind the scene i am just updating its bool property from false to true so the user can not see it ..

Comment: What i really want is to restrict any one to run delete query on sql and it is working fine for me